# Not getting $_REQUEST['signed_request']

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to pass some variables to my facebook app from the url, i.e. using GET variable `app_data` like facebook wants.

At some point I've stopped getting the `['signed_request']` part of the $_REQUEST. When I `print_r($_REQUEST)` I'm getting: `['doc']`, `['user']`, `['__utmz']`, `['__utma']` and `['session']` values, but not signed request :(

Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4):

Check the tab/canvas url is EXACTLY the same as required. If there is a redirect to another page, then signed request and other values will not be sent. You can check using a browser sniffer, if a call to the page responds with a 300 (301/302 etc) redirect, then you need to change to what it redirects to.

Examples:

https://example.com/ may need to be https://www.example.com/  (add www., or remove www. depending on how server is set up)

www.example.com/ may need to be www.example.com/index.php (add index.php, or the right page).

Check you are using http:// and https:// correctly in the URLs, and that https:// returns a valid page.

Comment: "You can check using a browser sniffer, if a call to the page responds with a 300 (301/302 etc) redirect" fixed it!

http://SITE.com page was redirecting to http://www.SITE.com, so iwas loosing the request.
 will add to the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

I've only been able to get the signed request in https://, i get no request at all in http.

Currently have a bug on FB, but no word on fixing it yet; http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/264505123580318?browse=search_4eb3ef23eb18d6649415729

---

EDIT:

http://SITE.com was redirecting to http://www.SITE.com, so I was loosing the request variables.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue, for me it was as simple as a mismatch of the app id and app secret! However in facebook developers backend I have noticed that the URLs all need to have that trailing slash!

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers do redirect your request to https automatically if you have been on this particular site on https so if you are in http mode on facebook there is situation:

facebook requests http version of your app, browser redirect this request of facebook to https and POST data and thus signer_request are gone in this process...

i see this problem in chrome 23, if you delete browsin data (particulary Deauthorize content licenses) app should run back on http

Comment: Does the browser do this by himself – or is it maybe a matter of _HTTP Strict Transport Security_, which some browsers and some servers are starting to implement nowadays?

Comment: it seems that in new firefox this is not the case, so probably it is just bug of chrome becasue it does not redirects correctly - ommits POST data on the way. But i am not expert, never  heard about  _HTTP Strict Transport Security_.